# Can you use a table as a column in SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm working with code from other people and see some use of Oracle SQL that I don't understand:

```
  SELECT
    column1, column2,
    (
      SELECT columnA
      FROM tableA
      JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_b_fk = tableB.my_pk
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS column3
  FROM tableC
  ...
```

I have trouble understanding why they use this:

```
(
  SELECT columnA
  FROM tableA
  JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_b_fk = tableB.my_pk
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) AS column3
```

Did they just use a table as a column? I thought you can only use columns?

Can you really do that? How does it work?

I don't know where to find explanation of this usage so I ask here.

Please correct me if there is any misunderstanding!

Comment: are you sure it is columnA **,** columnB and not columnA **||** columnB?

Comment: It is columnA only, I have made a mistake in the question code. I have revised and fixed the mistake

Comment: This is called a *scalar subquery* and it is rather common in SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I don't believe that the code you presented actually works:

```
SELECT
    column1, column2,
    (
      SELECT columnA, columnB
      FROM tableA
      JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_b_fk = tableB.my_pk
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS column3
FROM tableC
```

It is basically the same as:

```
SELECT 1 AS c
   , (SELECT 'a', 'b' FROM dual)
FROM dual
-- and will yield
-- ORA-00913: too many values
```

The construct you see is a **scalar subquery** in SELECT list (it is not a table per se). It has to return one row and one value(thus you have `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`).

```
SELECT 1 AS c
   , (SELECT 'a' FROM dual)  -- one column and one value subquery
FROM dual
```

---

If you want to return more than one column per row in outer query you could use `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT column1, column2, s.*
FROM tableC
OUTER APPLY (SELECT columnA, columnB
             FROM tableA
             JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_b_fk = tableB.my_pk
             FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) s
```

Still to make thing right it should be correlated subquery. More info:

- [Scalar Subquery Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Scalar-Subquery-Expressions.html#GUID-475D80C3-C873-4475-AB1A-8837C5CF8CE4)
- [Using Subqueries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Using-Subqueries.html#GUID-53A705B6-0358-4E2B-92ED-A83DE83DFD20)

Comment: It is columnA only, I have made a mistake in the question code. I have revised and fixed the mistake

Comment: @HenryYang So as I wrote it is not a table but Scalar Subquery expression.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your answer and the URL provided for more info! I think I understand what the expression means now. But can you clarify the following for me please? For the first URL, it mentions scalar subquery expression cannot be used as default values for columns, does that means the column listed in `SELECT` statement are not default values? If that's the case, what are default values for column? And also, I see that you writes `SELECT 1 AS c`, does that means you want to create a table with a column named c and make all rows of that table have a c column with value 1?

Comment: And lastly, can I assume `dual` table is a table that only has two elements instead of two columns with more than 2 elements? because you didn't use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` which mean you will be getting more than one element if `dual` consist more than 2 elements, and according to your answer, that will not be able to form a scalar subquery.

Comment: @HenryYang `DEFAULT VALUES for COLUMN` => It has nothing to do with `SELECT` but DDL like `CREATE TABLE t(i INT DEFAULT (SELECT 1 FROM dual))`. You will get error "ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here"

 `Dual` pseudotable always contains one row (so I don't need any fetch first). `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dual -- 1`

Comment: I see, thank you for the extra explanation! I understand it now!